# eventbus inside recursive function

Tags: android, event-bus

i am posting event using EventBus inside a recursive function that fetches pagination data from the webservice.

```
public void getCallsData(final UserRequest userRequest){

        serviceCall.enqueue(new Callback<UserResponseInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserResponseInfo> call, Response<UserResponseInfo> response) {

                if(response.isSuccessful()) {

                    UserResponseInfo userResponseInfo = response.body();

                    if (userResponseInfo != null) {
                        try {
                            Log.e(TAG, "getCallsData response " + LoganSquare.serialize(userResponseInfo));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        int currentPage =  userRequest.getUserRequestInfo().get(0).getPage();
                        int totalPages = userResponseInfo.getTotalPages();

                        if(currentPage < totalPages){

                            userRequest.getUserRequestInfo().get(0).setPage(++currentPage);
                            Log.e(TAG, "getCallsData fetching next page "+currentPage);
                            userResponseInfo.setCurrentPage(currentPage);
                            userResponseInfo.setRequestType(GET_CALL_REQUEST);
                            EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(userResponseInfo);
                            getCallsData(userRequest);


                        }

                    } else {

                    }
                }else{

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserResponseInfo> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

The issue is `EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(userResponseInfo);` when `getCall` executes in recursive fashion its not posting the event properly as in only first event is getting called and it misses the last one.

Comment: not "properly"?

Comment: only the first event is getting posted not the last one

Comment: add `Log.d` when your `getCallsData` begins and returns and watch the logcat, is the execution path correct (every begin matches return)?

Comment: it didnt match only the last event log i can see but it post only first event